# DateTime.ToString() format error

Tags: c#, datetime, format, string-formatting

I am using the following format to convert a DateTime to a string

```
setting.SettingValue = dt.ToString( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff" );
```

however the value is not as expected. The `SettingValue` property contains this value

```
2014-01-07 23.14.59.000
```

which uses a different time separator (`.`) instead of the specified one (`:`)

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't specified a format provider, so it's using the one from the current culture. If you *always* want to use `:`, you should specify an appropriate provider, e.g.:

```
setting.SettingValue = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff",
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```